# apt-key broken, exit code 2

Tags: apt

I was trying to add a PGP key for non-Ubuntu packages when I realized that any `apt-key` request is doing nothing (no output, no configuration change) and the program exit with code 2, except for `--usage`.

How can I fix it? Is there a debug output file of `apt-key`? Or in last case, is there a way to reinstall easily apt/apt-key without destroying my current configuration?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by `any apt-key request`? What exact command are your running? Also, try running it through `strace` to show why it's exiting with code 2.

Comment: I have tried `wget -qO-http://some.path/to/key | sudo apt-key add -` which was my original request and then `apt-key list` when the first failed. I ran it with strace but I am not able to intepret the output.
One line seems interesting anyway : `wait4(-1, 0x7fff6f0a5c14, WNOHANG|WSTOPPED|WCONTINUED, 0x7fff6f0a5c30) = -1 ECHILD (No child processes)`

Comment: Here is a link to the full output : https://pastebin.com/hURKnrPw. If I understand well the latest signals, `apt-key` asks `gpgconf` to do some task but it exits earlier than scheduled. I have tried to `apt-get install --reinstall gpgconf` but nothing changed.

Comment: Is the `strace` from the piped command? What happens if you try it in two steps, e.g. first download the key, maybe look at it (with `less`) if it's really a key you downloaded, then try `apt-key add keyfile` again? Hm, maybe `strace -f` again, or look in the logfiles referenced in `apt-key`.  Or, since `apt-key` itself is a shell script, maybe run this via `sh -x`. Did this all work before, is this a new problem? If it's eproducible on a fresh install, this would warrant a bug report ;-)